# How to remove network locations from this pc

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-8.1

There is a nice guide to [How to remove `Folders` from `This PC`](http://www.howtogeek.com/168081/how-to-remove-the-folders-from-my-computer-in-windows-8.1/) (they are stored in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MyComputer\NameSpace\`), but I cant find a guide like this for `network locations`. Is there any way to remove them?

[image]

Comment: Can't you `right click > disconnect`?

Comment: @MichaelFrank you are right! I can simply `Remove device` and they dissapear. Thank you

Comment: I'll add it as an answer for you. :)

Comment: Hi, for me, right click > remove device doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just `Right Click > Disconnect OR Remove Device` on any of those to remove them. The same goes for Mapped Network drives.

Comment: Actually this works only for short period of time, about 2 weeks later these networks locations appeared again

Comment: @DarkWalker - it has only been 1 week since I answered your question. But regardless, it's possible that media sharing is causing this issue. Since they are on your network, you may be accessing files from them or your computer is automatically finding media sources for you.

Answer (score 0):

right click remove does work on my windows 10. but they come back after a time (reboot?) very annoying. the only way I could get rid of one of them was to delete the user from the originating pc! did not try to re-add that user...
could not do this for the other uses as they are actually using that pc.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still trying to hide 'Network Locations' from 'This PC' in Windows 10 File Explorer, I found the below instructions from https://www.howtogeek.com/222057/how-to-remove-the-folders-from-this-pc-on-windows-10/. Backup the registry and then delete both of the below keys. The second one is applicable only to 64-bit versions of Windows 10.

```
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MyComputer\NameSpace\DelegateFolders\{b155bdf8-02f0-451e-9a26-ae317cfd7779}

Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MyComputer\NameSpace\DelegateFolders\{b155bdf8-02f0-451e-9a26-ae317cfd7779}
```